# Notify changes in object to parent angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have big object in my component, the properties in the object are bound to various components and inputs in the template:

```
  constructor() {
    this.data = {
      identifier: null,
      isRequired: true,
      title: 'Untitled',
      type: this.fileTypes[0].name,
      description: '',
      //more code here
}

<app-text-input [(model)]="data.title" label="Title" type="text" variant="white">
```

Since, all properties in `data` are bound with various input elements, the values in the object are kept updated. This component is child of another component.

The parent needs to have access to the `data` object when some event occurs (button click for example) on the parent. How do I achieve this? I know there are `@Ouptuts` but the event is happening on the parent not on child. Also, I'm not using any FormControl classes for now, do I need to implement that to achieve this?

Comment: You want to "notify" only if the event happens in the child and need the child to notify the parent. If the event happens in the parent, there is no need of "notify". Just directly get the data from the child in the event handler. The child can expose the `data` field. The parent can use [@ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) to get the reference to the child then read the `data` field.

Comment: How do you know the object properties are updated? Do you have any events which notify? There could be different ways to achieve it, but when we talk about the large object and having meta data for every component in it needs to be addressed efficiently. How many child components are we taking in here? And Are all these components are child, siblings or don't have any relationship?

Comment: @RickyMo what you're saying makes sense, will try that

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do this.

#### 1. Use a `BehaviorSubject`.

This would be best when using [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) instead of `ngModel`:

Child Component:

```js
@Input()
data: BehaviorSubject<T>;

form = new FormGroup({
  title: new FormControl()
});

ngOnInit() {
  this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(formData => {
    this.data.next({
      ...this.data.value,
      ...formData
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <input [formControlName]="title">
</div>
```

Parent Component:

```html
<child [data]="data"></child>
```

```js
data: BehaviorSubject<T>;

buttonClicked() {
  // use this.data.value
}
```

#### 2. Use [two-way binding](https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding).

This still uses `ngModel`, but will require you to customize the two-way bindings you are using on form elements to trigger the update:

Child Component:

```js
@Input()
data: T;

@Output()
dataChange: EventEmitter<T>;
```

```html
<input [model]="data.title" (modelChange)="data.title = $event; dataChange.next(data)">
```

Parent Component:

```html
<child [(data)]="data"></child>
```

```js
data: T;

buttonClicked() {
  // use this.data
}
```

You could also mix & match these, e.g. use two-way data binding on ngModel as in 2., but pass a `BehaviorSubject` from parent to child as in 1.

Answer (score -1):

Edit : Here is the way via event emitter, you need to subscribe to it in child component when the data is changed or emitted, Updated values will be displayed in child or any other component.

[Event emitter Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/event-emitter-angular-6-maymxr?file=src/app/check-events/check-events.component.ts)

**shared service**

```
SharedService
subject: Subject<Object>;

Parent-Component
constructor(DataService: DataService)
this.DataService.event.next(data);

Child-Component
constructor(DataService: DataService)
this.DataService.event.subscribe((data)=>{
   //emitted event with updated data
});
```

Whenever the parent emits using the next method, you can receive the data
in child or other component and act on it.

Comment: This is the most straight forward method which is also mentioned in the docs. The problem here is the I need the `data` when an event happens on the parent and not on child. So, I wouldn't know to explicitly call `sendToParent()`

Comment: In that case i would prefer event emitter and subscribe to the event , As data is bound with various component. Updated my answer.